# Fixed width, minimum width and fastest minimum width unsigned 8 bit integer

Tags: c, type-conversion, c99

Three days back I read an [article on choosing `correct integer size`](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2008/06/efficient-c-tips-1-choosing-the-correct-integer-size/). Before reading this article, I was unaware of these three keywords viz:

1) Fixed width unsigned 8-bit integer: `uint8_t`. (Typedef's are C99 complaints)

2) Minimum width unsigned 8-bit integer: `uint_least8_t`.

3) Fastest minimum width unsigned 8-bit integer: `uint_fast8_t`.

So my question are:

1) What exactly they mean by saying "at least 8 bits wide" for `uint_least8_t` & `uint_fast8_t`. For example, let's take a look at snippet of code

```
for(u16 i=0;i<counter;i++)
{
  Increment_Counter++;
}
```

Here :- u16 means unsigned short.
counter and Increment_Counter are two variables

When the `counter =0xFF`; Increment_Counter will work fine by any type of keyword declaration.
Now when `counter =0x01FF`; what kind of declaration should I choose? `uint_least8_t` (who guaranteed to be at least 8 bits wide) or unit16 type?

2) How choosing `uint_fast8_t` affects the code speed.

3) How choosing `uint_least8_t` consumes lesser data memory than unsigned char.

I webbed my doubts but got nothing. So any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `uint8_t` etc. are typedefs, not keywords

Comment: for your code snippet in (1) you will need to explain what `u16`, `counter` and `Increment_Counter` are, it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: My apology. I add "u16 means unsigned short, counter and Increment_Counter are two variables" and I want  to choose the correct integer for variable "counter".

Comment: What do you mean by "Typedef's are C99 complaints"?

Comment: All modern CPUs have 32 bit registers, unless you are writing games for a 'retro' 8bit Gaming machine eg. Atari or Commodore64 I wouldn't use these data types. Today int and long are exactly the same, unless you are writing for very old Hardware. Sinclair have said they are relaunching their 1980s gaming machine, so there is a point to a very new Standard to define old data sizes ( 8 and 16 bit binary).

Comment: @chux These typedef's are used  in header 'stdint.h' file

Comment: why are your questions numbered 1, 1, and 2?

Comment: @M.M Real programmers use Fibonacci numbering

Comment: @ArifBurhan Are Atmel AVR microcontrollers 'retro'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) What exactly they mean by saying "at least 8 bits wide"

It means the compiler will map this to a type appropriate for your target, but the only guarantee you have about this type is that it's at least eight bits.  Your concern should not be limited to the question of "What type should I make this index that guards a postincrement" -- you should focus on just sane usage within those 8 bits.

So, yes, be on the lookout for overflow but really think hard about whether it makes any sense with your design.  Does this have anything to do with user-input, for example?  Or are we counting some static elements of your design, perhaps?  Let's say `uint_fast8_t framistan_modules` is declared to count the number of "framistan" functions.  You have only defined 3 and you can't imagine why you'd ever need more than 5.

> 2) How choosing uint_fast8_t affects the code speed.

It's difficult to say anything about code speed without empirical metrics. But the idea behind this type is that my compiler might choose a register-width type for `uint_fast8_t`, even if my registers are significantly larger than 8 bits.

> 3) How choosing uint_least8_t consumes lesser data memory than unsigned char.

This is  <strike>unlikely to be the case</strike> impossible.  However, it's similar to the `_fast8_t` in that you're giving the compiler a degree of freedom (not merely exactly 8 bits).  The difference here is that you're not optimizing for speed like in `fast`, so there may be a different balance between register width and some other.

---

In general, if you've gotten far enough to be asking these questions, you would likely gain much by just witnessing the different code that's generated in these conditions.  And in all likelyhood you'd be well served by measuring the performance and memory consumption for each.

Comment: "This is unliklely" -> "This is impossible" ; the standard guarantees that `unsigned char` (and the other narrow character types) are the smallest possible addressable unit of memory.   `uint_least8_t` must be the same size as `unsigned char`, or larger.

Comment: I was very nearly confident that was the case.  But I retreated to something else that was true but less specific because I didn't have the relevant section(s) of the specification regarding the size of `unsigned char` in mind.

Comment: To repeat, all modern CPUs have 32 or 64 bit registers. 8 and 16 bit data are only relavent if you are writing for 'retro' hardware, eg. Sinclair Spectrum.

Comment: @ArifBurhan, `uint*t` and it's siblings are not bound strictly to registers.  Is your point that no one should ever use `uint8_t`?  If so, I think you're mistaken.  Memory-mapped I/O is just one obvious use case that comes to mind.

Comment: @BrianCain I am a bit confused thinking about uint_least8_t. In general, what is the significance of it then as declaring a variable as uint_least8_t will also roll over after 0xFF (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: @ArifBurhan "all modern CPUs have 32 or 64 bit registers" is incorrect.  100s of millions of processors in 2015 do not have any wider register that 16-bits.  Embedded processors far outnumber general purpose ones.

Comment: @ShaswatDube A `uint_least8_t` variable **might** roll over after 0xFF, or after 0x1FF, or after 0x3FF, or ... or after 0xFFFFFFFF, or ...